# Define the linear transformation $R$ by $Rz = \langle y,z\rangle x$. Prove that $R$ is bounded and compute its norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

The question is the following:

> Let $\mathcal{H}$ be a Hilbert space and $x,y \in \mathcal{H}$. Define the linear transformation $R$ by $$Rz = \langle y,z\rangle x \quad \forall z \in \mathcal{H}$$ Prove that $R$ is bounded and compute its norm.

I noticed that I may use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, but I can't see how it is actually bounded. Any help and hint are appreciated.

Comment: This is precisely using Cauchy-Schwartz, taking the i.p. out from the norm would do the trick. $||<y,z>x||=|<y,z>|||x||\leq ||y||\cdot ||z||\cdot ||x||$

Comment: C-S just says $\|Rz\|\le\|y\|\|z\|\|x\|$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown But can we just say that $||x|| \cdot ||y||$ is the desired constant? What if like they are infinity, will what be a problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $z=y/\|y\|$, then $\|z\|=1$ and $Rz=\|y\|\|x\|$, so the norm is attained.